# Grouping of Million Data Points slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple table containing 2 float columns representing X and Y coordinates. A non clustered index is on each of those 2 columns. In this table there are about 5 million datapoints which I want to group into custom grid using such an SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(X) Count, AVG(X) CenterX, AVG(Y) CenterY
FROM DataPoints
GROUP BY FLOOR(X / 5), FLOOR(Y / 5)
```

On a test case I splitted a data set with 815000 points into a grid where each point gets his own grid cell. It took the SQL server 2012 **26000 milliseconds** to provide the results which is definitly too long. I made a C# implementation of the same grouping using LINQ on a simple point array and there it only took **3450ms**! I also created a stored procedure of the SQL for some speed-up, but still it takes 26-30seconds to calcualte the grid cells.

I can't understand why it takes the SQL Server that long to calcualte those groups. I know it might take long on all 815000 poitns to calculate the grid cell index but 7 times longer than on a simple C# program can't be a realistic result.

I also tried to use spatial types to do calculate the grid but those solutions are even slower. Using a geometry column and a spatial index (GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID) the built in `sp_help_spatial_geometry_histogram` needs 2:40min to calculate 4 grid cells containing the data.

Has anybody an idea how to speed up such a simple SQL? In the future this data will be sent to a map in the browser and there will be a lot of requests so <100ms would be an ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

What does the execution plan tells you?
why is this slow?

i suggest you put a nonclustered index on x and y (not separate),
is this result better?

Comment: This is the execution plan: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2ufu79j.jpg The heavy operations are of course grouping and the avg calculation. I also added the two column index but the query still takes that long to complete. I had the assumption that maybe not the server, but rather takes very long till all data rows are sent to the client. And after enabling the client statistics, I found out that the first response already is sent after 3600ms which is basically the same time like my C# code. Is there possibly another performance improvement I can do, to get this task done faster?

Comment: I would like to play around with your data to see if it would be possible, Could you send me the table definition, and the totalt count of rows it got, i will recreate the data for further study!

Comment: The data is randomly generated. You can download it here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxHJCurpGhQ4YXdGVC1SamhjWjg/edit?usp=sharing  The table has 2 simple float columns: https://gist.github.com/Danielku15/a2698a028feffd040ed8

Comment: I totally forgot about this, i have imported the data in my localdb instance, running on a normal desktop disk, i get a total execution time: 396 in average, what sql server are you testing this on?